# Retrofit2 handle JSON response that contains two models data

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 to handle http request after calling from API. Let me explain this.

I have **2** java class(POJO) created to handle user and lecturer data which is `User.java` and `Lecturer.java` respectively. For the response data such as :

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "user_id": "28",
      "user_email": "john@abc.com",
      "user_password": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

i can use `User.java` class to handle this response. Nothing complex in this file, only contains `getter` and `setter` method. Same goes to lecturer data, here is the example of lecturer data :

```
{
  "lecturers": [
    {
      "lecturer_id": "3",
      "user_id": "28",
      "lecturer_name": "johny2"
    }
  ]
}
```

i can handle it by using `Lecturer.java` class.

But the problem is, if the response contains both user and lecturer data on a single json, how to handle it?? . Here is the example of request :

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "user_id": "28",
      "user_email": "john@abc.com",
      "user_password": "123",
      "lecturer_id": "3",
      "lecturer_name": "johny2"
    }
  ]
}
```

To solve this problem, i think i need to create another java class that contains both `User` and `Lecturer` class on it, unfortunately at here i'm stuck.

This is new file, that i tried to create *(Userlecturer.java)* :

```
public class UserLecturer {

  User user;
  Lecturer lecturer;

  // how to implement on this part
}
```

Here is `UserLecturer` interface :

```
public interface UserLecturerInterface {

  @GET ( "api/endpoint/here" )
  Call<UserLecturer> getLecturerByUserId (@Path( "userId" ) String userId );

}
```

Appreciated for any helps. Ask me for more inputs if above use case did't clear enough. Thanks

Comment: I think that's the correct solution. Do you find any problem?

Comment: @RaymondLukanta problem is, how to write `getters` and `setters` code inside  `UserLecturer` class, in order to make those `getters` avaialable to call inside retrofit2's success callback

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali You can just extend the class, `public class User extends Lecturer` and redefine the api `Call<User> getLecturerByUserId `. But beware of inheritance.

Comment: @b1izzard the inheritance part for this case is not suitable.. Because later on, user data might be have another entity mixing together. Right now, only user data mix with lecturer's data. Later might be mix with another data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the POJO should be:

```
public class Users {
    String userId;
    String userEmail;
    String userPassword;
    String lecturerId;
    String lecturerName;
}
```

Even though there are 2 models inside the JSON, you only need 1 model for Retrofit.

---

If you **really** want to split the 1 JSON response into 2 models, I think you have to implement custom JSON converter.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(UserLecture.class, new JsonDeserializer<UserLecture>() {
                public UserLecture deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                    JsonArray usersJsonArray = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("users");
                    JsonObject userJsonObject = usersJsonArray.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setUserId(userJsonObject.get("user_id").getAsString());
                    user.setUserEmail(userJsonObject.get("user_email").getAsString());
                    user.setUserPassword(userJsonObject.get("user_password").getAsString());
                    Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer();
                    lecturer.setLecturerId(userJsonObject.get("lecturer_id").getAsString());
                    lecturer.setLecturerName(userJsonObject.get("lecturer_name").getAsString());
                    return new UserLecture(lecturer, user);
                }
            })
            .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl([YOUR_BASE_URL])
.addConverterFactory(GsonFactoryConverter.create(gson))
.build();
```

Comment: This POJO got mixed with lecturer's data. I already have `User ` and `Lecturer`'s POJO separately. I think this is not got idea. Since later than, response data might contains another data as i'm joining the tables inside database to got the results just per one request. Yeah, if have lecturer data only combined with user, then your idea is good to use.

Comment: If the JSON structure is like that, I think you can't use the default Retrofit JSON Converter.

Comment: So, no way for me to create another POJO class that contains both User and Lecturer?

Comment: You can try Ali's answer below.. I think that will work.

Comment: Yeah, trying in progress. Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I've updated my answer. I also have tested the code and it's working :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers mate. Got it working right now.. Yeah, this is the true answer. I'm using both concept from you and @Ali 's answer

Answer (score 2):

This is some code I use to convert longs to Java Date objects.
Presumably, you can do the same thing for your UserLecture object. You should be able to extract the individual json objects for User and Lecture, create a new UserLecture object and let User and Lecture as objects in it.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(UserLecture.class, new JsonDeserializer<UserLecture>() {
            public UserLecture deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                JsonObject user = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("user");
                JsonObject lecture = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("lecture");
                return new UserLecture(user, lecture);
            }
        }).create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonFactoryConverter.create(gson))
    .build();
```

Then inside `UserLecture`:

```
public UserLecture(JsonObject userJson, JsonObject lectureJson) {
   this.user = new User();
   this.user.setUserId(userJson.get("user_id").getAsInt());
   this.user.serUserEmail(userJson.get("user_email").getAsString());
   //so on.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this. Where should i implement this above code?

Comment: Retrofit uses Gson or some other JSON library to build Objects from the json response. Look at the configuration section here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ I assumed you used Gson as that is the most common configuration as it is a smaller and library than Jackson.

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify how to configure Gson. Note, I haven't tried this, just have a feeling this should work. If you declare an object to type UserLecture, this deserialize method should be called in order to deserialize it.

Comment: Yeah, i use gson as a converter and all the single response successfully parse by the converter automatically. But stuck if the response didt match with the existing POJO.  I got how the way it implements but got erros on this line `User user = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("user");
                User lecture = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("lecture");`

Comment: Seems like values got from `getAsJsonObject("user");` returned as a Json Object rather than User object.

Comment: Yes, that's right, that's my mistake. You have to convert the Json to Object manually, that's the whole point of this unfortunately. I would create a constructor that takes a JSONObject and builds the User or takes all the fields individually. It's a little cumbersome but it's the best way.

Comment: I've update the code with an example of how to build `UserLecture` from the `JsonObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. That is the best solution in my case. I got it working by modifying a few snippet but all major code i'm using Raymond and yours. Thanks mate for the hard time. If i could accept the answer twice, Really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

At first let me say that the JSON you need to process here is broken by design so you should urge the guy / department / company to fix it.

Secondly, JSON processors like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) allow to parse polymorphic data structures like this easily, but they require some kind of `type` flag to distinguish one of another type (i.e. `type: "user"` and `type: "lecturer"`). There is also a way to do this without such `type` flags, but there is a lot more hand work involved. The [last example here](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.de/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. Will try to look at it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is one possible solution. Gson ignores all fields, which names doesnt match @SerializedName annotation. So, you may try another solution without creating any more pojo classes- return result as String, and try to parse this string as both classes. If one result is empty- then you have another. But, if both kbjects isnt empty- then original response contain fields from both pojos

Comment: So i need to do it manually for parsing response coming from an API instead of using POJO class. Thanks for idea. Will try to implement it.

Comment: no, you should not do it manually. Gson parser will do it authomatically, but, if field's name in response is not found, it will use default value. You may try to parse the same response as User and Lecturer classes

Comment: Hmm, things going bit confuses. Can you share just a simple example?